# How to create custom navigation buttons for swiper in react?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Swiper react has a documentation in witch it is not explained how to add custom navigation buttons.

I tried this and it didn't work

I'm using swiper 8.0.5

```
<Swiper
                modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
                spaceBetween={50}
                slidesPerView={1}
                onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
                onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
                navigation={{
                    prevEl: '.prev',
                    nextEl: '.next',
                }}
                pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            >
                <SwiperSlide><img className="m-auto" src="/Images/Swiper/1.jpg" /></SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide><img className="m-auto" src="/Images/Swiper/2.jpg" /></SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide><img className="m-auto" src="/Images/Swiper/3.jpg" /></SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide><img className="m-auto" src="/Images/Swiper/4.jpg" /></SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide><img className="m-auto" src="/Images/Swiper/5.jpg" /></SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use react refs to add custom Navigation buttons as follow:

```
function MySwiper() {
  const prevRef = useRef(null);
  const nextRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={1}
        onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
        onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
        /*using the refs instead of className*/
        navigation={{
          prevEl: prevRef.current,
          nextEl: nextRef.current,
        }}
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      >
        {/*your slides here */}
      </Swiper>
      <button ref={prevRef}>previous</button>
      <button ref={nextRef}>next</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**HOWEVER, keep in mind that react ref is NULL at the first render.** So if you do not have a state that re-renders your component, the buttons **won't work**. my work around it is adding a state that will be updated on swiper initialization:

```
function MySwiper() {
  //Add a state that will force a re-render
  const [_, setInit] = useState();

  const prevRef = useRef(null);
  const nextRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        /*using the refs instead of className*/
        navigation={{
          prevEl: prevRef.current,
          nextEl: nextRef.current,
        }}
        /*update state on swiper initialization*/
        onInit={() => setInit(true)}
      ></Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me
**[swiper/react] Custom navigation/pagination components using React refs not working/possible?**
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3855#issuecomment-982499163

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).